# Groovy Server Pages (.gsp) test if variable is string

Tags: groovy, gsp

I have the following code in a Groovy Server Page:

[image]

How can I check if the value of `IntegerNameValueListName` is a string in general and not compare it only to one specific string ?

`IntegerNameValueListName` has the following value:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual Java `instanceof` operator should work, but bear in mind that GString values are not `instanceof String` so this may give you false negatives. Depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve a simple `!= ''` or even a Groovy-truth `test="${IntegerNameValueListName}"` may be enough.